# Why using of PowerMockRule for bootstrap tests affects tests which use PowerMockRunner for bootstrapping?

Tags: java, powermock

I have several tests which are using PowerMockRule to bootstrap to avoid classloading issues, as it is recommended in documentation for PowerMockito:

> The main difference between the agent based bootstrapper and the classloading based bootstrapper is that you don't run into classloading issues when using XML frameworks etc. It's recommended to use this way of bootstrapping when using PowerMock for integration testing larger parts of a system.

In the same package of tests I have tests which are using PowerMockRunner with @RunWith annotation. I have unexpected issue in these tests which looks like this:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 12
Exception Details:
  Location:

    javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext; @1: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ac7 000b bb00 3d59 b700 3ebf 2abe 0464
    0000010: 3d1c 9b00 172a 1c32 c700 0bbb 003d 59b7
    0000020: 003e bf84 02ff a7ff eb2a 2bb8 0040 b0
```

Why PowerMockRule affects tests which are using PowerMockRunner?

If I remove the tests which are using PowerMockRule then all works fine.